# Return an RAII object from a function

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

In C++14, I am trying to define a "RAII factory" function, something like this:

```
// Here, "ScopedReseource" is a plain RAII class, managing some resource.

ScopedResource factory(/* args */) {
    return ScopedReseource(/* args */);
}
```

Client usage would be:

```
{
    auto scoped = factory(/* args */));
    // use scoped...
}
```

As I understand it, copy elision is not guaranteed by the language in C++14, so this is not reliable.
In particular, it could result in ScopedResource's destructor being called at the end of the `factory()` function (and a new copy made at the callsite). I don't want that.

The traditional client code works fine, of course:

```
{
    ScopedResource scoped(/* args */);
    // use scoped...
}
```

Now, I have tried removing `ScopedResource`'s copy constructor (`=delete`), and defining a move constructor. The code compiles, and it only does construct/destruct once, which is what I want — but is it portable?

So, questions:

- Am I right that returning an RAII object (where the destructor does special work that I want done exactly once) is not feasible before C++17?

  - Is my approach of removing the copy constructor and defining a move constructor valid/portable?
- Am I right that in C++17, you *can* portably do it with the naïve code above?

Or are there some other nuances here that I am missing?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` does exactly (as far as I can tell) what you're asking about. It was added to the standard library in C++11, and doesn't require any implementation-specific tricks. So, yes, it can be done portably before C++17.

Comment: @PeteBecker See the discussion in the answers for details. You're right, but the way `unique_ptr` accomplishes that is by tracking state, and having the destructor do different things depending on whether it is "empty". So following that pattern, `ScopedResource`'s destructor *would* be called multiple times (what I was trying to avoid), but it would have logic in it to avoid doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Re: "destructor would be called multiple times" -- yes, that's correct. Why is avoiding that a goal?

Comment: @PeteBecker The point of this destructor is to have one-time-only side-effects. For example, `std::lock_guard` is roughly similar to my case (and it is non-movable for good reason, as I now comprehend better). More discussion in this vein under Nicol Bolas' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right that returnining an RAII object (where the destructor does special work) is not feasible before C++17?

In general, no.  An RAII type should be built to handle being copied/moved so that it can be returned by value.

In your specific case you are correct that you need C++17's guaranteed copy elision since your RAII type does not do that. (Which means it's not really an RAII type)

> Is my approach of removing the copy constructor and defining a move constructor valid/portable?

It's a valid way to stop an object from being copied, but again before C++17 the object could be moved out of the function and the destructor ran on the stub that is left in the function.  If you goal is the destructor is not called until the object is destroyed in the call site then this is not the solution for you.

> Am I right that in C++17, you can portably do it with the naïve code above?

Yes.  In C++17 and beyond

```
ScopedResource factory(/* args */) {
    return ScopedReseource(/* args */);
}

auto scoped = factory(/* args */));
```

boils down to

```
auto scoped = ScopedReseource(/* args */);
```

---

If you can't guarantee that you'll have C++17, then you can use a `std::unique_ptr` to encapsulate your object.  This will ensure that even if RVO/NRVO is not applied you object is not destroyed.  That would give you

```
std::unique_ptr<ScopedResource> factory(/* args */) {
    return make_unique<ScopedReseource>(/* args */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly unique_pointer is not great for me because I don't want heap allocations. I guess the traditional way is the only way for me (:

Comment: I guess with the move constructor approach, I *could* set some flag or other state to indicate it was moved, then check that in the destructor, making it a no-op? Getting a bit complicated, though.

Comment: @jwd You could do that.  It is kind of strange that you have an RAII type that you can't copy.  The whole part of RAII types is to allow copies/moves that "do the right thing".

Comment: Point taken. I guess I'm taking a pessimistic approach, where I support the minimum number of operations needed. The RAII usage in this case is just to instantiate the object on the stack and use curly braces to control the length of ownership of that resource — similar to usage of a mutex. I actually find it weird that a user would want to copy or pass around such objects. It's different for things like shard_ptr, of course.

Comment: It looks like there was some comment exchange here that I missed. Deleted comments on SO are annoying ):

Comment: @jwd No worries about it.  Was just about clarifying the answer some more.

Comment: I wonder if some of the friction on this topic is due to my use of the term "RAII" to describe what I want. You wrote in your answer "Which means it's not really an RAII type". Is there a better term for something where you want to use object lifetime/scope to control when some begin/end actions are performed? In my mind, that falls under the RAII umbrella (akin to a mutex lock). But maybe my terminology is off?

Comment: @jwd Really the friction comes from that fact the you have copy/move constructors but they don't leave the object in a state where the destructor can be called correctly.  If you type is copy/move-able then you need that logic otherwise it's not really an RAII type.  You deleted the move the copy constructors like `mutex` does then it would be RAII because it "handles" those operation (by not allowing it).  You need C++17's guaranteed copy elision though to have a factory function for a type like that.

Answer (score 3):

> As I understand it, copy elision is not guaranteed by the language in C++14, so this is not reliable. In particular, it could result in ScopedResource's destructor being called at the end of the factory() function (and a new copy made at the callsite). I don't want that.

Why not?

If your type is moveable, then that means the moved-from object will contain a "null" resource. That is, it won't currently be associated with a resource. Therefore, its destructor will do nothing, and the resource being managed will still exist.

So there's no problem in C++14 with returning such an object by value. Yes, a destructor may get called, but since it doesn't do anything, who cares?

> Am I right that returning an RAII object (where the destructor does special work that I want done exactly once) is not feasible before C++17?

No, you are incorrect. So long as you code your object to have a "null" state that represents not having a resource (which is standard for move-only types), the "special work" will only be done by a single object. Multiple destructors may get called, but only one such call will do the important part of releasing the resource.

This is about properly implementing a move-only type, not about copy elision.

Comment: Re "Why not": I suppose the short answer is that the RAII class is not written very robustly (:  I agree that a null/empty state would address the issue, but it would still result in unnecessary code being run. I suppose I should have written "Am I right that returning a *stateless* RAII object...". Copy elision nukes all of these issues in this particuar case, so it seems still a relevant aspect of the discussion?

Comment: @jwd: "*it would still result in unnecessary code being run*" Who decides that it is "unnecessary?" How would you be able to move the object *anywhere* if you don't have an empty state? You seem to want it to be mobile, but you don't seem to want to pay the price for that mobility. C++17 doesn't let you do that; it just gives you one tiny corner case where you can get away with it. It doesn't avoid things like trying to stuff such an object into an `optional` or a `vector` or any number of other circumstances where you might want such a thing.

Comment: Re "Who decides that it is 'unnecessary'": for sake of argument, let's say that I do. I don't especially want a mobile class, sorry if I gave that impression. I was merely trying to use `move` to accomplish my goal in C++14. For context, imagine a braindead RAII-style class whose destructor is just "run some code that has side-effects" (let's say `printf`, for simplicity). I want a scoped object to control when that printing happens, and I don't want that printing to happen twice. Adding state to solve the issue is extra data and code to worry about which C++17 avoids. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jwd: "*Does that make sense?*" No. In the context of a type whose destructor "runs some code that has side-effects," what is the point of a factory function? What is your factory doing that a *constructor* could not? Factory functions are usually for cases where you need multi-stage object construction. If all your constructor does is store some data so that you can cause some side-effects, why do you need a factory? That is, I don't understand the use case for an object which is logically immobile *and* needs a factory.

Comment: @jwd: It should also be noted that even the various scope guard types proposed for C++ like `scope_exit` are move-constructible and have an empty state.

Comment: Well, I'm not defending the original design; I'm wiser after having posted this question (:  I have since switched it to be a plain constructor. But offhand, I believe `std::lock_guard` is non-movable, so has similar semantics to the thing I'm discussing. Why might someone want a `lock_guard` factory? Well, perhaps the specific implementation might be chosen in some dynamic way, so you ask the factory "give me the lock_guard that is appropriate for me"  (I realize I'm being hand-wavy). Here, the factory is less about multi-stage construction, and more about dynamic choice of implementation.

Comment: At the risk of angering the SO "you should move to chat" gods: just to be clearer for my actual use-case: I'm dealing with an external c-style API which demands I run `beginX`, then do some stuff, then `endX`. I want to be sure begin/end are paired, so I'm using RAII. I felt the implementation might be swapped out in the future, so that's why I went for a factory approach (less client code to change when the impl changes).